# Including objects from join in query result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

Imagine a simple Entity Framework query with a context generated from the database such as:

```
var q = from a in context.Accounts

        join c in context.Contracts
        on a.Id equals c.AccountId

        select new CustomAccount {
            Id = a.Id,
            Name = a.Name,
            ...
            Contracts = //How do I easily populate the related contracts?
        };
```

The query looks for accounts and joins to contracts.  The relationship is not enforced in the database (I can't change the schema) so I can't use navigational properties.  Is there an easy way that I can populate the related objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you can execute a query that return *anonymous type* objects

**EDIT** : you can create a custom class to hold the data member of your result and return in linq result.

**EDIT** : using group by on account name (e.g)

```
    var q = from a in context.Accounts
            join c in context.Contracts
            on a.Id equals c.AccountId
            group a by new { a.Name } into g
            select new AccountContracts
            {
               AccountName = g.Key.Id,    // Account name
               Contracts = g.SelectMany(x => x.Contracts)
            };
```

Comment: This is true, but that's not what I am looking to do.  I can't have my method return an anonymous `List`.

Comment: It's a one to many relationship.  The property was "Contracts" implying a `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this still doesn't get me what I'm after.  I need more than just a single value from the account, and using a long list of properties to group by (which is what @shuniar suggested) seems unwieldy.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on your question what is your expectation output...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `group by` clause. Something like this (untested):

```
var q = from a in context.Accounts
        join c in context.Contracts on a.Id equals c.AccountId
        group a by new { a.Id, a.Name, a.Etc } into g
        select new CustomAccount
        {
            Id = g.Key.Id,
            Name = g.Key.Name,
            Etc = g.Key.Etc,
            Contracts = g.SelectMany(x => x.Contracts)
        };
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and while I haven't tested it, the listing of all the columns for both grouping and projection is a bit ugly (I'm going to have lots of columns).